# unable to create a row on the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I want to align these two boxes in a row at the center of the page like this:

[image]

each of the two boxes above has this HTML code:

```
<!-- box-container start -->

<div class="box-container">

<div class="subbox-container">

    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box1" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.655px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(49.3315px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->


    <!-- Start Box -->
    <div id="box2" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.655px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(49.3315px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

        <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
            <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
              <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
           </text> 
        </svg>

        <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

            <defs>

               <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
               </linearGradient>

               <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                  <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                  <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                  </feGaussianBlur>
                  <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
               </filter>

            </defs>

            <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

            <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
               <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                  <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
               </g>
               
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- End Box -->

</div>

<!-- background rectangle -->
<div class="background-rectangle" style="height: 177.257px; width: 260.673px; z-index: 999999;">
    <svg height="128.31" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 186" data-commandset-id="35" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <g >
            <path d="M259.147003,1E-06C266.245483,-1.2E-05 271.999939,5.754436 271.999969,12.852937 271.999969,12.85294 271.999969,12.852942 271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,171.147034C271.999969,178.245529 266.245514,183.999985 259.147034,183.999985L259.147034,183.999985L12.852946,183.999985C5.754463,183.999985 3E-06,178.245529 0,171.147049L0,171.147049L0,12.85295C-5E-06,5.754468 5.754446,7E-06 12.852927,-1E-06z" id="uniqueDomId-1466" fill="#E6E0EC" fill-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC1DA" stroke-opacity="0.14" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

</div>

<!-- box-container end -->
```

in order to have two of them in a row on the center of the page I wraped them in a container named `main-container` and with a flex box css like this:

```
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

But I only can see one of them on the page?! why? what I misssed?

Here is the whole code in action:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Heebo-Light";
  src: url(Heebo-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
}

svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}


body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box svg:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.background-rectangle {
  transform: translate(49.3315px, -24.31px);
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.box-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 

<div class="main-container">


    <!-- box-container start -->

    <div class="box-container">

    <div class="subbox-container">

        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div id="box1" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.655px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(49.3315px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

            <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
                <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
                  <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
               </text> 
            </svg>

            <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <defs>

                   <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                   </linearGradient>

                   <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                      <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                      <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                      </feGaussianBlur>
                      <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
                   </filter>

                </defs>

                <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

                <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
                   <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                      <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
                   </g>
                   
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->


        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div id="box2" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.655px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(49.3315px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

            <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
                <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
                  <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
               </text> 
            </svg>

            <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <defs>

                   <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                   </linearGradient>

                   <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                      <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                      <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                      </feGaussianBlur>
                      <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
                   </filter>

                </defs>

                <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

                <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
                   <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                      <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
                   </g>
                   
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->

    </div>

    <!-- background rectangle -->
    <div class="background-rectangle" style="height: 177.257px; width: 260.673px; z-index: 999999;">
        <svg height="128.31" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 186" data-commandset-id="35" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <g >
                <path d="M259.147003,1E-06C266.245483,-1.2E-05 271.999939,5.754436 271.999969,12.852937 271.999969,12.85294 271.999969,12.852942 271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,171.147034C271.999969,178.245529 266.245514,183.999985 259.147034,183.999985L259.147034,183.999985L12.852946,183.999985C5.754463,183.999985 3E-06,178.245529 0,171.147049L0,171.147049L0,12.85295C-5E-06,5.754468 5.754446,7E-06 12.852927,-1E-06z" id="uniqueDomId-1466" fill="#E6E0EC" fill-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC1DA" stroke-opacity="0.14" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>

    </div>

    <!-- box-container end -->

    <!-- box-container start -->

    <div class="box-container">

    <div class="subbox-container">

        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div id="box1" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.655px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(49.3315px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

            <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
                <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
                  <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
               </text> 
            </svg>

            <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <defs>

                   <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                   </linearGradient>

                   <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                      <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                      <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                      </feGaussianBlur>
                      <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
                   </filter>

                </defs>

                <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

                <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
                   <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                      <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
                   </g>
                   
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->


        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div id="box2" class ="box" style="margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 257.829px; height: 42.655px; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 128.914px 21.3277px; transform: translate(49.3315px, 84px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);" aria-label="do you ever">

            <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 172 45">
                <text font-family="Heebo-Light" font-size="24px" fill="#595959" fill-opacity="1" x="50%" y="53%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle">
                  <tspan>do you ever</tspan>
               </text> 
            </svg>

            <svg height="42.655" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 45" preserveAspectRatio="none">

                <defs>

                   <linearGradient gradientTransform="rotate(90, 0.5, 0.5)" id="uniqueDomId-1114">
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#AFAFAF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F5F3F8" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="69.804%" stop-color="#F9F9F9" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
                   </linearGradient>

                   <filter id="uniqueDomId-1115" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="-15.75" y="-15.75" width="303.5" height="76.5">
                      <feFlood result="floodOut" flood-color="#CCC1DA" flood-opacity="0.29"></feFlood>
                      <feGaussianBlur result="gaussOut" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="2.450000047683716,2.450000047683716">
                      </feGaussianBlur>
                      <feComposite in="floodOut" in2="gaussOut" operator="in"></feComposite>
                   </filter>

                </defs>

                <use transform="translate(-2.72, -0.45) scale(1.0199999809265137, 1.0199999809265137) translate(0, 0)" xlink:href="#uniqueDomId-1116" filter="url(#uniqueDomId-1115)" data-angle="0" data-distance="0" data-height="45" data-scale="1.02" data-adornment-type="drop-shadow" data-width="272" data-transform="[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;translate&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[-2.72,-0.45]},{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;scale&quot;,&quot;args&quot;:[1.0199999809265137,1.0199999809265137]}]"></use>

                <g id="uniqueDomId-1116">
                   <g id="uniqueDomId-1117">
                      <path d="M0,0L272,0 272,45 0,45z" id="uniqueDomId-1118" fill="url(#uniqueDomId-1114)"></path>
                   </g>
                   
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->

    </div>

    <!-- background rectangle -->
    <div class="background-rectangle" style="height: 177.257px; width: 260.673px; z-index: 999999;">
        <svg height="128.31" width="162" viewBox="0 0 272 186" data-commandset-id="35" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <g >
                <path d="M259.147003,1E-06C266.245483,-1.2E-05 271.999939,5.754436 271.999969,12.852937 271.999969,12.85294 271.999969,12.852942 271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,12.852945L271.999969,171.147034C271.999969,178.245529 266.245514,183.999985 259.147034,183.999985L259.147034,183.999985L12.852946,183.999985C5.754463,183.999985 3E-06,178.245529 0,171.147049L0,171.147049L0,12.85295C-5E-06,5.754468 5.754446,7E-06 12.852927,-1E-06z" id="uniqueDomId-1466" fill="#E6E0EC" fill-opacity="0.7" stroke-width="1" stroke="#CCC1DA" stroke-opacity="0.14" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-linejoin="round" data-stroke-sharpened="true" transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>

    </div>

    <!-- box-container end -->





</div> <!-- main container end-->


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:** here is the uexpected margin:

[image]

It is not set anywhere and if I try to set `margin 9 !important` it doesn't go away... also I noticed when I remove the width of background rectangle the margin removes but the width fill the space again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've position the two boxes one on top the other, this will fix your problem:

```
.main-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: 0;
}
.box-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer plus one ... one last question: how to get ride of the margin of background-rectangle that is a wired and unexpected margin not set anywhere... I'll edit the question to show that...

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're trying to use flex positioning and absolute positioning at the same time. Because the `.box-container`s are `position: absolute`, they're removed from the "flow" of the page --- so they're ignoring your flexbox rules. Instead, they're both placed on top of each other (this means your second box is "hiding" the first one). If you remove that part of the CSS, you'll get closer to what you're looking for!

You'll still have some issues to solve (centering the row vertically within the page, because `top:300px` won't be doing anything anymore), but it should be more clear what's going on!

Comment: There are also unexpected and wired margins to the right of the background-rectangle?!

Comment: @SaraRee There may be -- the best way to figure out what's going wrong is to simplify the example -- first just try positioning two div elements, then add text, then add the SVGs (Stackoverflow question answerers also are more likely to respond to a simplified code sample!)